# show bootstrap carousel caption out of image wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need to show `caption` out of image wrapper(bottom of image) in `bootstrap carousel` Like This Pic. in `.carousel-caption` `class` i set `position relative` and `top : 300px` but my `caption` not work over the image `wrapper`. how to fix his?

[image]

CSS Code:

```
 /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 500px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin:0 auto;
      top: 300px;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {


      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/examples/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1280/1024/technics" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-centered">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1280/1024/abstract" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Live Previe [here](http://www.bootply.com/78286)

Answer (score 0):

Your container `div` needs to contain the image and the caption.
It only contains the caption in this example.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" height="400"alt="" />
                                <div class="carousel-caption" style="color:red; width:100%;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                            <div>
                                                <h2>Haby Scholarship</h2>
                                                <h3>By Haby Digital</h3>
                                                <h2>Commerce</h2>
                                                <p>Description...</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="images/slide2.jpg" height="400"alt="" />
                                <div class="carousel-caption" style="color:#68217A;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div style="width:100%;">
                                                <h2>Phael Scholarship</h2>
                                                <h3>By Phael Digital</h3>
                                                <h2>Information Technology</h2>
                                                <p>Description...</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="container">
                                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" height="400"alt="" />
                                <div class="carousel-caption" style="color:#DF6026;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-7">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            <div style="width:100%;">
                                                <h2>Haby-Phael Scholarship</h2>
                                                <h3>By Haby-Phael Digital</h3>
                                                <h2>Science</h2>
                                                <p>Description...</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left slider-arrow-margin-left"><span style="color:#808080;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right slider-arrow-margin-right"><span style="color:#808080;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-control {
  background:none;
}



.carousel-control.left{
     background-image:none;
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     filter:unset;
   }

.carousel-control.right{
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: unset;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .image-wrapper-bg {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 2px solid #9AA5A7;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next,
    .carousel-control, .carousel-control {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .slider-arrow-margin-left{
        margin-left:-100px;
    }
     .slider-arrow-margin-right{
        margin-right:-100px;
    }

    .image-wrapper-bg{
        width: 94%;
        margin:0 auto;
        border:2px solid #9AA5A7;
        margin-right:0;
    }
    .caption {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .image-wrapper-bg{
        width: 84%;
        margin:0 auto;
        border:2px solid #9AA5A7;
    }

    .slider-arrow-margin-left{
        margin-left:-30px;
    }

    .slider-arrow-margin-right{
       margin-right:-30px;
    }
     .padding-slider-caption{
        padding:20px 20px 20px 40px;
    }
    .caption{
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}

.padding-slider-caption{
    padding:20px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .image-wrapper-bg{
        width: 70%;
        margin:0 auto;
        border:2px solid #9AA5A7;
    }

    .padding-slider-caption{
        padding:20px 20px 20px 40px;
    }

    .caption{
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}

.padding-slider-caption{
    padding:20px;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {

    .carousel-caption{
        position:realative;
        /*background-color: hsla(360, 100%, 100%, 0.5);*/
        color:#68A667;
        margin-top:-10px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5;
        padding:15px;
        z-index: 10;
        bottom:200px;
    }
}

@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:991px) {

    .carousel-caption{
        position:realative;
        /*background-color: hsla(360, 100%, 100%, 0.5);*/
        color:#68A667;
        margin-top:-10px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5;
        padding:15px;
        z-index: 10;
        bottom:0;
    }
}
```

Overwriting the bootstrap allows you to place the caption wherever you want. #bootstrap #CSS #Responsive